# How to compile a linux app to run on a shared web server

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation

I am trying to get a small C application to run on my web server.  The web hosting company is HostGator and we have their least-expensive plan 'Hatchling'

Unfortunately this particular plan does not provide access to a compiler, which means I'll need to build it on a similar machine to that server and transfer the executable there.

My question is how 'close' do I have to get to the Linux distribution on that web server for this to work?  I currently have a recent Ubuntu in a VM and would like to use it for this process but maybe some complex differences in how Ubuntu compiler chain is built versus what can work on the web server are too great?

Would I need to install the CentOS release 6.5 they use and compile on that?

What do you recommend I do to attack this problem?

John,

P.S. Hostgator runs 'CentOS release 6.5 (Final)' and /proc/version returns "Linux version 3.2.52 (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC) )"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is worth checking that the architecture is the same e.g. Intel - 32bit or 64bit.  In theory 32bit will work on a 64bit architecture as long as supporting libraries have been installed.

Dependancies are the other challenge you will have.

Versions of GCC and Kernel versions do not matter too much.

Comment: Thanks very much Billy, this particular CentOS box appears 64-bit (uname -a returns Linux gator3069.hostgator.com 3.2.52 #9 SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) and my Ubuntu box also 64-bit... so you think that a simple bare bone app that listens to a socket and perform a bit of processing can work without me setting up a CentOS box?

Comment: I would try compiling - use static libraries - I expect it will work.